# Special characters problem? utf8towcs error. How to fix it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I don`t know what happened with the scrip.

Few days ago works. But today don´t display me the chart, only give me this error code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  invalid input 'Aín' in 'utf8towcs'
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  invalid input 'Aín' in 'utf8towcs'


"Aín" its a town in the .csv   I don´t know how to fix this....
```

This is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)

library('data.table') 




dfcsv <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/15810be9-d797-4bf3-b37c-4c922bee8ef8/resource/8ab99a46-1d04-42b4-8ee4-0cc5821be976/download/2020-06-05_casospormunicipio.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
colnames(dfcsv) <- c("code","Municipio", "PCR", "Tasa PCR", "PCR14", "Tasa PCR14", "Muertos", "Tasa Muertos")


dfcsv %>%
  mutate(Municipio = fct_reorder(Municipio, PCR)) %>%


  ggplot(aes(x=Municipio, y=PCR)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Changing encoding to ASCII worked.